# How to construct finite fields of any prime power order?

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

For a prime $p$, I know that $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field. To construct a field with four elements, I know I can just take $\frac{\mathbb Z_2[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}$. Similarly, to construct a field of order $p^n$, do I just need to take $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ and quotient out an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$? Is there any pattern to these irreducible polynomials, or do I just have to find one by brute force?

Comment: This reference might be useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polynomial_(finite_fields)

Comment: Pari has a function (*ffinit*) which given $p$ and $n$ outputs an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$. The documentation says it uses "a fast variant of Adleman and Lenstra's algorithm", which I suppose refers to http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1986a/art.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any general procedure to find an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. However, any such polynomial $p(x)$ works, i.e. it will produce a field $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p(x))$ of order $p^n$.

Comment: Also, why is is that this always gives fields isomorphic to each other?

Comment: A way to prove this is to show that any field of $p^n$ elements is a splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^n} - x \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, and then use that any two splitting fields for the same polynomial are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "construct" such fields, when $n$ is a power of 2, and $p \neq 2$, you can do the following:

- Start with a field with $p$ elements.
- Such a field will always have an element that does not have a square roots. Let it be $Q$.
- Construct a field with $p^2$ elements with each element given by $a + \sqrt{Q} b$ where $a$ and $b$ are elements in the field

Above procedure can be repeated as many times as needed. If you write computer programs, or you want a concrete representation that does not involve square roots then you can set up an isomorphism between the new field and a subset of $2\times 2$ matrices in the original field as
$$
a + \sqrt{Q} b \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ Q^2 b & a \end{pmatrix} $$

This will allow you to do all your work in the base field (also very useful if you want to write computer programs and don't mind being a bit inefficient).

Answer (score 1):

hey there yes for constructing a field with $p^k$ elements where $p$ is a prime number and $k$ is a natural number you can take any $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ which is irreducible of degree $k$ then using that theorem you have a field with $p^k$ elements